# I want to add more primary key into existing primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to set primary key by combining 3 columns but by mistake i set the key with one column. How should i add other two columns into existing primary keys.

```
CREATE TABLE facultyQualification(
    facultyID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    level_ VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Exam_Degree VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    School_College VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Board_Uni VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    year_of_passing DATE NOT NULL,
    Max_marks_grades INT NOT NULL,
    marks_grade_obtained INT NOT NULL,
    perscent_marks INT NOT NULL,
    division VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    achievement VARCHAR(50),
    FOREIGN KEY(facultyID) REFERENCES facultyPersonal(facultyID)
);
SELECT * FROM facultyQualification;
ALTER TABLE facultyQualification
ADD PRIMARY KEY (facultyID);
```

The primary keys i wanted to make are (facultyID,level_,year_of_passing).

Comment: Drop the bad primary key and then create it again with all three columns.

Comment: plz send me the code, idk how to do it

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
alter table facultyQualification drop primary key;

alter table facultyQualification 
add primary key (facultyID, level_, year_of_passing);
```

See example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sQREHCYdRFrwKNQBDCiyHD/0).

Comment: It gives an error "cannot drop index primary: needed in foreign key constraint"

Comment: Then there's another table that already has a reference to this table. You'll need to recreate that other table as well.